# Changing a variable affects an indirect variable (value vs reference)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Given the following code:

```
    Rect pos = new Rect();
    for (int i = 0; i < mCols; i++) {
        pos = mTiles[1][i].getmPos();
        pos.top = pos.top - size;
        pos.bottom = pos.bottom - size;
        mTiles[0][i].setmPos(pos);
    }
```

What I want to do is get the value from

```
mTiles[1][i].mPos
```

modify it, and set it in

```
mTiles[0][i].mPos
```

The problem is this statement

```
pos = mTiles[1][i].getmPos();
```

is copying the reference to the object and not the value of the object.  Meaning, when I modify pos.top or pos.bottom, the original object gets modified.

I'm guessing I am missing a concept of pass object by reference vs value here...which I thought I understood.  What is the fix here?  Is it a problem with how I defined my custom class?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
Rect pos = new Rect();
for (int i = 0; i < mCols; i++) {
    pos = new Rect(mTiles[1][i].getmPos());
    pos.top = pos.top - size;
    pos.bottom = pos.bottom - size;
    mTiles[0][i].setmPos(pos);
}
```

?

Comment: Ahh nice.  Never thought of doing it that way.  Tested and works.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a temporary Rect to change the values with, and only assign the values, not the entire object:

```
Rect pos;
for (int i = 0; i < mCols; i++) {
    pos = new Rect();
    pos.top = mTiles[1][i].getmPos().top - size;
    pos.bottom = mTiles[1][i].getmPos().bottom - size;
    mTiles[0][i].setmPos(pos);
}
```

Comment: That shouldn't work based on my problem.  Perhaps I'm not explaining it right.  The pos object isn't ever set to a value, it's set as a reference to the object mTiles[0][i].mPos.

Comment: Yeah, my mistake, I just edited my answer as I realised what was going on... still not 100% sure if it'll work though :$

Comment: OK, I see you edited.  Yes, correct, I need to assign values not a reference...so how do I accomplish that without having to code every .bottom, .top, .left, and .right?  Trying your solution now.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks. I'm simply frustrated with having to each property of the Rect (aka Rect.top/Rect.bottom).  Why can't I copy the value of the whole Rect.